# Employment length in Lending Club data R

Tags: r, data-science

I have employment length data that looks like this.

```
chr [1:39786] "10+ years" "< 1 year" "10+ years" "10+ years" "1 year" "3 years" "8 years" "9 years" "4 years"
```

[image: The data before any changes]
Currently I'm doing this script to turn it to numeric data. It's horrible.

```
newdata$emp_length <- gsub(" years" , "", newdata$emp_length)
newdata$emp_length <- gsub(" year" , "", newdata$emp_length)
newdata$emp_length <-gsub("n/a",0,newdata$emp_length)
newdata$emp_length <-gsub("< 1",0.5,newdata$emp_length)

set.seed(1)
temp1<- c(1:length(newdata$emp_length[which(newdata$emp_length == '10+')]))
for (w in c(0.18,0.17,0.15,0.13,0.10,0.09,0.07,0.05,0.03)){
  assign(paste0("sample", w), sample(temp1,8899*w, replace = FALSE))
  temp1 <- temp1[!(temp1 %in% get(paste0("sample", w)))]
}

temp2 <- newdata$emp_length[newdata$emp_length == "10+"]
temp2[sample0.18] <- 10
temp2[sample0.17] <- 11
temp2[sample0.15] <- 12
temp2[sample0.13] <- 13
temp2[sample0.1] <- 14
temp2[sample0.09] <- 15
temp2[sample0.07] <- 16
temp2[sample0.05] <- 17
temp2[sample0.03] <- 18
temp2[temp1] <- 19
newdata$emp_length[newdata$emp_length == "10+"] <- temp2

newdata$emp_length <- as.numeric(newdata$emp_length)
```

The loop creates 9 random samples. Then, I 'randomly' assign the numbers from 10 to 19.

Is there a better way to do it?
Is it better to just assign 10 to all the "10+" values?

data comes from :(https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action)

Comment: It looks like your question is not about programming, but about 'how to handle censored data'. Interesting topic, it depends on the specific analyses you intend to do with these data. If this is the case, I am afraid that SO is not a good destination for this. Maybe Cross-validated?

Comment: I'm also interested in how to improve the script. It's repetitive

Comment: `ifelse(newdata$emp_length == "10+ years", sample(10:19, nrow(newdata)), as.numeric(gsub('[ a-z]','',newdata$emp_length)))` does most of the processing in one line. It gives `NA` values to '< 1 year' fields though, so you may want to handle separately that case.